# Connecting to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

How do I connect using MSSMS (Microft SQL Server Management Studio)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zack Skyles describes this in a [blog post](http://english.zachskylesowens.net/2009/08/18/connecting-to-sql-azure/)

You must cancel the first connection box when opening MSSMS, select *New Query* and then add your server and credentials and select your database under *Options*

Update: Using MSSQL Management Studio 2008 R2 (currently as CTP) it works fine without the tweak above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only have access to one database at a time - there is no cross-database stuff. That stops Object Explorer working, and also means that when you connect, you have to choose the Options, to set the name of the database you want to connect to.

Once you're in, you can query sys.objects (and more), to be able to navigate as you need.

But it's not your standard SSMS experience, since you don't have the Object Explorer.